# How can you quickly check if you package.json file has modules that could be updated to newer versions?

Tags: node.js, npm

How can you quickly check if you package.json file has modules that could be updated to newer versions?

For example, a quick way to check if either express or nodemailer has an available update?

```
{
    "name": "some_module_name"
  , "description": ""
  , "version": "0.0.3"
  , "dependencies":  {
           "express": "3.1"
         , "nodemailer" : "0.4.0"
    }
}
```

I read over the FAQs, but didn't see anything:
https://npmjs.org/doc/faq.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes there is an option :

```
npm outdated
```

This will list modules, with available updates. It supports syntax for specifying the module name.

According to the [Documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/outdated.html), the syntax is

```
npm outdated [<name> [<name> ...]]
```

This gives you to specify the module name you wish to check exclusively, like

```
$ npm outdated mongoose
```

#### Note

To use this properly, you'll have to add a version number of the target module(s) with range `greater than` or `greater than or equal`. You can check [node-semver](https://github.com/isaacs/node-semver), which is integrated into `npm` to check the syntax.

#### Example

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.2.0",
        "mongoose": ">= 3.5.6",
    },
}
```

Will give the following result ( since today the latest mongoose version is 3.6.9 )

```
$ npm outdated
...
mongoose@3.6.9 node_modules/mongoose current=3.6.7
$
```

While if you place

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "express": ">= 3.2.0",
        "mongoose": ">= 3.5.6",
    },
}
```

The result will be :

```
$ npm outdated
...
mongoose@3.6.9 node_modules/mongoose current=3.6.7
express@3.2.3 node_modules/express current=3.2.0
$
```

Comment: Thanks because I didn't know about it. I'm not sure it does exactly what I wanted after testing `npm outdated`. It seems like it checks to see if you have a version number in you package.json file that hasn't yet been downloaded. I don't think it actively checks to see what the absolute latest version of the package is. For example, I tested it with a module - uglify-js. I installed an older version in my node-modules, then ran `npm outdated uglify-s` but it doesn't alert me to the fact that latest version of uglify-js is 2.3.0.

Comment: Yep, you have to use `>= x.xx`, where `x.xx` is your minimum version number of the module you want to use. This way after you run `npm outdated` it will display something similar to this : `mongoose@3.6.9 node_modules/mongoose current=3.6.7`. This will automatically check all of your modules from the npm-server, which is the official database, you should know that not every module updated in `npm` exists or is updated in github.

Comment: Awesome. I just tested. That is __exactly__ what I wanted. The documentation is not clear about the need for ">= X.X.X" although it makes sense. Good point about every module not being on github. Would you mind added the ">= X.X.X" part to the official answer, and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 3):

there's a service like travis that checks it automatically:

https://gemnasium.com

Comment: Cool. Thanks for sharing. Definitely an overkill for what I need. However, good to have on the radar.

Answer (score 2):

you need to do that manually using the update command:

```
$ npm update
```

you can also change the version:

```
"nodemailer": "*" // this would use the newest version
```

or

```
"nodemailer": ">=0.4.0" // this will install any version which is at least 0.4.0
```

and so on....

read more about that here: https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#dependencies

EDIT: there is some possibility if the module is available via github. you can then "watch" that repo, and get notification updates!

Comment: Thanks. I think watching git might be the only way. Or writing your own script. (I'm surprised nothing seems to be available on npm for this. I just spent some tien looking over packages.) There should be a command such as `npm potential_updates` that check the 'stable' and 'latest' fields and compares it to what you have in your package.json file. Then, simply outputs a list like: `nodemailer: you have: 0.4.0, current stable is: 0.4.1,  latest is: 0.4.2`   Maybe I'll try writing this later. (But I'm sure somebody already has! :D)

Comment: I marked this as correct because I think it's current state until I find or write a script for it. Thanks!

Comment: This will update your modules, not only check if `has modules that could be updated`

Comment: @drinchev is right. `npm outdated` does the trick on this. Thanks for all the answers on this.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out https://david-dm.org/ as it is free service that does the check. This is more target at adding a build badge to your README, but the details it gives on the page are quite helpful.

See https://david-dm.org/jshint/jshint as an example output.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll check it out. You can't comment yet because you're new to the sight and need more points. I remember that. I wanted to pass on information but my only option was to answer the question. Annoying isn't it? They should let people comment before write a response. ;D

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found is to use: [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check) install with npm / yarn and then to update the outdated packages interactively: `npm -check -u`